# I am trying to make django app but this script error keeps coming

Tags: python, django

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from buttonpython2 import views
app_name = "buttonpython2"
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.button)
    path('', views.output, name="script")

]
```

this is my url.py
this image shows the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8UbF.png)

Comment: You use two URL patterns with the same pattern, hence `views.output` can never be triggered, only `views.button`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you used `app_name = 'buttonpython2'`, you should *prefix* the view name with the `app_name`, so:

```
{% url 'buttonpython2:script' %}
```

this will however *not* trigger the `output` view, since the pattern (completely) overlaps with that of the `button` view, and since the `button` path is defined before the `script` path, it will ths trigger the `button` view. You thus should define another path for the `views.output`.

Comment: You thus should define another path for the views.output. how do i trigger
path('', views.output, name="script")

Comment: @SACHISINGH: use a different path, so `path('foo/', views.output, name='script')`.

Comment: path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.button)
   

    path('foo/', views.output, name='script')
like this?

Comment: @SACHISINGH: yes, you can of course use something else than `foo`, but the path patterns should be distinct.

Comment: 'buttonpython2' is not a registered namespace this error is coming

Comment: @SACHISINGH: did you reference to your `urls` module somewhere in the root urls (the `project_name/urls.py` file)?

Comment: that was the whole code in urls.py

Comment: @SACHISINGH: but is this the *root* `urls.py`, or one for an app?

Comment: oh its not the root i am not sure why but i guess i made a copy

Comment: i will make this app again it got messed up